# Condition number

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain why the condition number of a singular matrix is always Inf? Or just direct me to a proof. It's stated as a fact in my textbook with no explanation.

Comment: The condition number is the ratio of the largest singular value to the smallest.  If the matrix is singular, the smallest singular value is zero.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways of interpreting the condition number, but generally the point is to get an upper bound on the sensitivity of the solution of a
system of equations to relative changes in input data.

If a system is singular, the solution is not unique (or may not exist), so it makes no sense to talk about sensitivity as such (or you can think of it
as being infinite).

For a non singular $A$, the condition number is $\operatorname{cond} A = \|A\| \|A^{-1}\|$, and if $A$ is singular, we define  $\operatorname{cond} A = \infty$,
more as a matter of convenience.

If we have a singular $A$, and $A_n$ is a sequence of non singular matrices
such that $A_n \to A$, then we have $\operatorname{cond} A_n \to \infty$,
so while the choice of $\infty$ is a convenience, it is also consistent
in some sense.